# High cpu usage by ruby interpreter after install

Tags: ruby

I've installed Ruby and the vscode extension so I can build a liquid theme for shopify.

The cpu usage is high when idle ~30%. After closing vscode the interpreter stays in memory and continues to use the same 30% cpu.

Is this normal? Does Ruby do some prep tasks in the background which will eventually complete and cpu will go to ~0 when idle and shutdown when I close vscode?

Or is the cpu usage always that high? I've looked around, [this mac issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864828/vs-code-process-ruby-on-macos-running-at-100-cpu-how-to-fix) hints at it being the case without additional configuration and another says recompilation of Ruby solved their high cpu issue.

I'm running on Win 10

Cheers